# Adding struct value to char array in C

Tags: c, linux, compiler-warnings

I have some value. Say it's

```
dir->d_name;
```

I want to add this value to char array

```
char fileNames[100];
```

I created a temporary char value trying to assign dir->d_name

```
char temp_fileName;
temp_fileName = dir->d_name;
```

How can I do that or maybe I should convert dir->d_name to char or string?

> Warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char*' makes integer from pointer
> without a cast

Answer (score 0):

As the warning says, this is a `char*` (`char` pointer), not a `char`:

```c
char* temp_fileName;
/*  ^-- Here */
temp_fileName = dir->d_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the reference (pointer):

```
char *temp_fileName;
temp_fileName = dir->d_name;
```

If you want to store the copy of the string:

```
char *temp_fileName = strdup(dir->d_name);
```

or

```
char *temp_fileName = malloc(strlen(dir ->d_name)+1);
if(temp_fileName) strcpy(temp_fileName, dir ->d_name);
```

or if `temp_fileName` is an automatic variable

```
char temp_fileName[strlen(dir ->d_name)+1];
strcpy(temp_fileName, dir ->d_name);
```